deployment.yaml: error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"
I am trying to run an application on my EKS cluster. The Kubernetes cluster is supposed to access an AWS EC2 instance with Mongodb installed on there. I've applied both a service.yaml file and deployment.yaml file. But the error I am getting is that my pods enter a "CrashLoopBackOff" Status because of my deployment.yaml file. The error message is: "error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"".
I double checked the connection string format with references and documentation online and I don't see anything wrong with this: mongodb://admin:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/admin
Am I missing something?
This is my deployment.yaml file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tasky
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tasky
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tasky
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tasky
        image: xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/tasky:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URI
          value: mongodb://admin:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/admin

Below is my main.go application
package main
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    controller "github.com/jeffthorne/tasky/controllers"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var client *mongo.Client

func index(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "login.html", nil)
}

func main() {
    // Load environment variables from .env file
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file: %v", err)
    }

    // Get MongoDB URI from environment variables
    mongoURI := os.Getenv("MONGO_URI")
    if mongoURI == "" {
        log.Fatalf("MONGO_URI not set in environment")
    }

    // Connect to MongoDB
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI)
    var err error
    client, err = mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error connecting to MongoDB: %v", err)
    }

    // Check connection
    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error pinging MongoDB: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")

    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("assets/*.html")
    router.Static("/assets", "./assets")

    router.GET("/", index)
    router.GET("/todos/:userid", controller.GetTodos)
    router.GET("/todo/:id", controller.GetTodo)
    router.POST("/todo/:userid", controller.AddTodo)
    router.DELETE("/todo/:userid/:id", controller.DeleteTodo)
    router.DELETE("/todos/:userid", controller.ClearAll)
    router.PUT("/todo", controller.UpdateTodo)

    router.POST("/signup", controller.SignUp)
    router.POST("/login", controller.Login)
    router.GET("/todo", controller.Todo)

    // Start the server
    router.Run(":8080")
}

Thank you in advance for any input or help!
So far I've checked:
The EC2 Instance with MongoDB:

Verified the EC2 Instance with MongoDB installed is running fine, no issues. The MongoDB config file grants access to all IPs, authentication is enabled in the config file and the admin/password has been setup on the database.

A .env file contains the Mongo connection string: MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/admin

Dockerfile includes access to the .env file: COPY --from=build /go/src/tasky/.env ./.env

My main.go application includes configuration to Mongodb



Try wrapping the value in quotes as sometimes yaml can be picky about values with colons in them value: "mongodb://admin:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/admin"

Thanks for your reply! I've tried that (both with and without quotes), but still same issue. I created a .env file (MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017/admin) and added it as a variable and referenced it in my main.go application instead of the yaml file and I still get the same cannot parse issue.

Try logging the value of mongoURI right after you check it is not the empty string.

Have you tried doing these:

Test the connection string locally (EC2 instance)?
How did you generate the password? Does it contains special characters? If yes, you might need to escape it.

Hope it helps!

Hi! Thanks for your reply! (1) Connection was tested locally on the EC2 instance and it connects successfully. (2) no special characters, just admin as user and password as password (for simplicity purposes)
